# How apache drill queries HBase?

Tags: java, hadoop, hbase, apache-drill

Does Hbase goes for a full scan every time when we fire SQL with condition on hbase columns? Or does drill uses some kind of indexing mechanisms to avoid the full scan.?

Also do we need to install drillbits on each region servers for best data locality.?

Comment: I couldn't find any document or related blogs that's why I posted in stack-overflow. Lets hope someone will share their thoughts even though your down vote will impact the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Drill would do a full table scan. However, the filter condition would be pushed into the scan resulting in better performance.
Please see the comment at the bottom of the page [How Apache Drill Queries HBase](https://drill.apache.org/docs/querying-hbase/)

> By taking advantage of ordered byte encoding, Drill 1.2 and later can
>   performantly execute conditional queries without a secondary index on
>   HBase big endian data.

Comment: There is nothing more than that single sentence. :) Could you please explain the ordered byte encoding. ?